# When are python class properties created

Tags: python

```
class Foo:
   bar = 1
   ......etc.
```

I know when creation a instance, bar is created before `__init__`,
I want to know if it is the very first thing to create the bar property when creating
a instance for Foo.
Also, does the bar already exists in memory before any instance is created?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html is usually worth reading when it comes to things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that in Python `class` is an executable statement (as too are `def` and `import`). So the answer to your question is that `bar` is created when the `class` statement executes.

Specifically, when a `class` statement executes, the body of the class is executed in a namespace that is usually just a `dict`. When the body has finished executing a class object is created with a copy of the resulting `dict` as the `__dict__` attribute for the class.
The dict at this point contains all the names bound inside the class body `bar=1` for example, but also any functions that were defined in the class body.

Instances, when they are created, don't get a copy of `bar`, they just refer back to the class. When you lookup a name on an instance Python looks in both the instance's `__dict__` and the class's `__dict__`.

Comment: A perfect answer for me. Thanks Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Those properties are stored in the the `__dict__` of the class itself. They **never** exist on the instance (or rather the instance's `__dict__`) unless you assign it manually.

For example, if you use `self.bar += 1` in a method you'll *read* the `1` from the class-level variable and assign `2` to the instance-level variable. The next time you run this statement, `bar` exists on the instance level so you read that `2` and replace it with `3`.

Comment: Well, I'm mainly curious when the bar property got is memory, before any instance is created?

Answer (score 0):

State variables will be assigned before the constructor (**init**). So...

```
    Class Foo:
        bar = 1
        def __init__(self):
            bartwo = 2
```

would see bar take on a value of 1, before bartwo was assigned, though. My guess is your question is "If I assign a state variable before a constructor, can I use it in the constructor. Yes.